# LazyInitialization Exception with wicket / hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, wicket

I'm using wicket and hibernate (jpa) on a simple webapp.
The Task.java is related to the Load.java as follows:

Task.java:

```
@ManyToOne( targetEntity=Load.class, optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)   
@JoinColumn(name="load_id")
public Load getLoad() {
    return load;
}
```

One task can have maximum one load, but one load can map to many tasks:
Load.java:

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy="load",targetEntity=Task.class,  orphanRemoval=false)
public Set<Task> getTasks() {
    return tasks;
}
```

The sessions (entityManager in JPA speak) are being created and attached to the thread by a transaction filter.

I have a page which lists Tasks, and shows the first 10.  When I click on the link to the next 10, it tries to load the Load for Tasks 11-20 (using getLoad), and for some reason throws a LazyInitializationException - even though there **is** a valid session for that thread (as can be seen in the stack trace, and debuggin).  I can't use EAGER loading since that will cause problems elsewhere.  I can check that the entitymanager is valid in the constructor of the LinkPanel and it is indeed valid.  However 3 lines later it throws a LazyInitializationException.  What's going on?

```
- could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at com.xxx.er.batch.beans.Load_$$_javassist_7.toString(Load_$$_javassist_7.java)
    at com.xxx.er.basman.model.LinkPanel.<init>(LinkPanel.java:41)
    at com.xxx.er.basman.pages.TasksOverviewPage$7.populateItem(TasksOverviewPage.java:130)
    at org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.grid.AbstractDataGridView.populateItem(AbstractDataGridView.java:187)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RefreshingView$1.newItem(RefreshingView.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.DefaultItemReuseStrategy$1.next(DefaultItemReuseStrategy.java:71)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.DefaultItemReuseStrategy$1.next(DefaultItemReuseStrategy.java:68)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RefreshingView.addItems(RefreshingView.java:189)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RefreshingView.onPopulate(RefreshingView.java:98)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onBeforeRender(AbstractRepeater.java:131)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractPageableView.onBeforeRender(AbstractPageableView.java:121)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1066)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1100)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1754)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3966)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1066)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1100)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1754)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3966)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1066)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1100)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1754)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3966)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onBeforeRender(Page.java:1550)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1066)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1100)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.prepareForRender(Component.java:2292)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.prepareForRender(Page.java:1540)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.prepareForRender(Component.java:2329)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:911)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycle.redirectTo(WebRequestCycle.java:201)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.PageRequestTarget.respond(PageRequestTarget.java:58)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:105)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
    at com.xxx.er.basman.HibernateTransactionFilter.doFilter(HibernateTransactionFilter.java:58)
```

Just to re-iterate, HibernateTransactionFilter creates an EntityManager like this:
`EntityManager em = myEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); 
em.getTransaction().begin();
entityManagerThreadLocal.set(em);`

In the LinkPanel constructor I'm checking this EntityManager as follows :

`EntityManager em = entityManagerThreadLocal.get();
if (em == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("No entity manager has been started on this thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }`

Comment: Strangely, I've discovered that I can work around this.  In the transaction filter, after running `chain.doFilter(request, response)` , I retrieve the EntityManager, then get the Transaction, and if it's not marked for rollback, I commit the txn and close the entitymanager.  Well if I commit the transaction, but leave the entitymanager open, then it seems to work around this problem.  Now I need to check it's not causing any others...

Comment: I've also noticed that wicket seems to send 2 requests when I click on the link in the view tasks page (the link which takes me to the page where I view tasks 11 - 20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because an entity manager is open doesn't mean that all lazy-loaded entities can be loaded. If the entities have been loaded by a different entity manager / session from the "current" one, the entities are still detached, and trying to load a lazy association on them will lead to the exception you're encountering.

In short, your filter opens an entity manager which makes lazy-loading possible for the current request. But as soon as the request ends, the entities become detached.

Either reload them at the second request, or reattach them to the current entity manager / session.

Comment: exactly, so either session.update(task) or session.lock(task) to reattach to the newly opened session.

Comment: Thanks for your swift and informative answers.  If I understand correctly, a Set of Tasks is loaded when I load the view tasks page, but then clicking to see the next (11-20) Tasks is a new request, with a new EntityManager, which doesn't know anything about the existing loaded Tasks.  So the approach would be to add a refresh / merge command each time we come across a Task which might not be in the current persistence context.

Comment: I seem to have got it working with your help. I run a refresh (merge) command while processing each object, and then **take the return value and assign it**: ie   `entity = DbHelper.getNonNullEntityManager().merge(entity);`.  This seems to have fixed the problem!  Only problem is the extra overhead (and possible DB calls) caused by all the refreshing.

Comment: merge is normally used to save modifications. You just want to reload it. Why don't you simply use find? entity = em.find(entity.getId())

Comment: @JB, good idea but I get the following error when I try this: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.xxx.er.batch.beans.Load_$$_javassist_7 `(where a Load is the item I'm reloading) - presumably that refers to an uninitialized child object...